# Adding three arguments to a dictionary but error message states it is expecting 2 arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to add a third argument to my dictionary **but get an error message that it is only expecting 2 arguments**.

```
from collections import deque

#setting up a dictionary so that only the recent most recent values are stored
player_stats = {}
with open("players.dat") as f:
for line in f:
    classcode, name, score = line.split()
    player_stats.setdefault(classcode, name, deque(maxlen=3))  
    player_stats[name].append(int(score))       

print(player_stats)
```

My data is: 1, rooney, 56 and so on for other players too.

I cant see why I get this error, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: A dictionary whose keys are names, and whose values are score lists, would probably be a good structure to work from.

Comment: Im sorry I don't understand, is there a resource you can point me to to read up on it. Thanks

Comment: how do you know which entries are most recent... are they the ones nearer the bottom of the file?

Comment: yes the ones near the bottom are the most recent, for each player the entries at the bottom for each player are the recent entries. I only want to keep a maximum of the three most recent entries for each player. I don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

If you really want a data structure which only ever stores the most recent three stats for each player (rather than storing them all and truncating it when you output them) you can use a `deque`:

```
from collections import deque

player_stats = {}
with open("players.dat") as f:
    for line in f:
        name, score = line.split()
        player_stats.setdefault(name, deque(maxlen=3))
        player_stats[name].append(score)

print(player_stats)
```

Comment: Is it possible to perform calculations on the items in the deque?

Comment: it's iterable so you can use functions like `sum` etc

Comment: I have tried adding the values for each player as follows but I get an error message, I believe it is because the values in the dictionary is a string. The code is as follows but I get errors:

Comment: with open("players.dat") as f:
  group = []
  for line in f:
    fields = line.split()
    group.append( (fields[0], int(fields[1])))
print(group)
                  
from collections import deque

player_stats = {}
with open("players.dat") as f:
    for line in f:
        name, score = line.split()
        player_stats.setdefault(name, deque(maxlen=3))
        player_stats[name].append(score)
        sum(player_stats.values())

print(player_stats)

Answer (score 0):

As @kevin suggested, use a dictionary with the player names as keys and a list of scores as the value:

```
scores = {}
with open("players.dat") as f:
    for line in f:
        fields = line.split()
        scores.setdefault(fields[0], []).append(fields[1])
```

The `setdefault` call adds a name (`fields[0]`) to `scores` if it doesn't already exist and sets up an empty list as that item's value. We then append the current score (`fields[1]`) to this list.

Now you have a `dict` with player names pointing to a list of all scores. To print only the last 3 scores:

```
for k, v in scores.items():
     print("%s -> %s" % (k, ", ".join(v[-3:])))
```

Here, I assume that the last 3 scores are what you want to display and hence to the `", ".join(v[-3:])`.

Comment: in Python 3 that should just be `score.items()`

Comment: Thanks @Anentropic, I have fixed the code to use `.items()`.